# Sharing session data across domains with PHP

Tags: php, html

My user is logged in at `site_url.com` on a CMS, however I am now developing a mobile version of the site, outside the CMS on a subdomain `m.site_url.com` and would like the session to be carried over.

I have included a file with all the CMS' functions like this:

```
<?php include_once'/home/flyeurov/public_html/core/codon.config.php';?>
```

I can login fine on the mobile site:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mobileVersion" value="True">
<input type="hidden" name="redir" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
<input class="login-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />
```

The above is processed by `login.php`. However, CMS login redirects it to CMS' page, and I need the mobile version to redirect to a page in /mobile directory where `m.site_url.com` subdomain points. Hence, in `login.php` (not to be confused with `mobile/login.php` - main `login.php` is for the CMS). I did this, and it redirects to `mobile/crew_center.php` - a page it should redirect to on a mobile version.

```
if (isset($_POST['mobileVersion'])) {
                header('Location: http://m.site_url.com/crew_center.php');
            } else {
                $this->post->redir = str_replace('index.php/', '', $this->post->redir);
                header('Location: '.url('/'.$this->post->redir));
            }
```

Maybe the above code has something to do with my problem.

My problem is that the session from the main CMS is not carried over to the mobile site. In `mobile/index.php` I have this statement, which does not work. When logged in, the user should see `crew_center.php` as it would be pointless to display the login form. At the moment, when the user is logged in on the CMS, the login page still appears on the mobile version.

However, if I drop the subdomain in the browser and type `site_url/mobile` it will open the right page `crew_center.php`.

```
<?php include_once'/home/flyeurov/public_html/core/codon.config.php';

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'site_url.com');
session_start();

if(Auth::LoggedIn())
{
    header("Location: crew_center.php");
} 
else
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

How can I fix this, and how can I share session data from a main domain to a subdomain with the use of PHP?

---

codon.config.php - http://pastebin.com/BWcbddGG

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the cookie's domain accordingly - add a `.` to your domain name:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.site_url.com');
```

This will share your cookie across all of your sub domains and the second level domain.

Comment: I thought it was a stupid mistake of mine, but this still points to `m.site_url.com/login.php` if you are logged in and type `m.site_url.com` in the browser.

Comment: I've just tested it locally and it works. Have you tried clearing your cookies? I also suggest you to add `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION); echo "</pre>";` after `session_start()` to see if the session will be loaded at all.

Comment: `Array
(
    [session_id] => i:450497;
)


Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/flyeurov/public_html/mobile/index.php:5) in /home/flyeurov/public_html/mobile/index.php on line 13` The page is not loaded at all, I get this error straight away.

Comment: Is `session_id` the identifier you use to check if a user is logged on or not? I've also checked your `codon.config.php` (didn't notice it) and the problem could be the call to `session_start` on line 2: You are sending the session cookie to the client before you call `session_set_cookie_params`, so it won't have any effect at all! (Remove `session_start` from `codon.config.php` to verify it)

Comment: Tried it, and I still get the error. I believe that the session cookie is `$_COOKIE['VMSAUTH']`

Comment: Did you comment out the `echo "<pre>"; ...` part and delete all existing cookies? Session data is not accessible through the `$_COOKIE` array because session variables are stored on the server. The only data available in `$_COOKIE` is the session id.